# Cannot get matching keys from Redis using redis-cli

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I have this:

```
$ redis-cli -n 2 -h "$host" GET events:from_bitbucket:fc2c0983-d0f2-4211-aa2e-5382afd9b288
"[object Object]"

$ redis-cli -n 2 -h "$host" GET 'events:from_bitbucket:*'
(nil)
```

why does the first query work, but the second query responds with (nil)? Makes no sense. Same host and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one good answer is simply:

```
redis-cli -n 2 -h "$host" KEYS 'events:from_bitbucket:*'
```

of course this only gives you all the matching keys, not the values.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that `GET` doesn't support wildcards. You could try something like this:

```
redis-cli <<< "scan 0 MATCH events:from_bitbucket:*"
```

**Sample Output**

```
1) "0"
2) 1) "events:from_bitbucket:fc2c0983-d0f2-4211-aa2e-5382afd9b288"
```